# How to secure the communication between API backend and SPA frontend

Tags: api, security, single-page-application

I am working a lot with SPAs*. Therefore I am using API based backends to get the entity data for the SPA-ORMs*. This is simple and works fine.

Now I am working on a private project that will be used by many people. I want to prevent the misusage of my APIs without the SPA. **Are there ways to make it a little harder for the script-kiddies to misuse the API?**

Back in my time :D I used to use simple keys to encrypt the data on a very low level. But with the current dev-tools of f.e. chrome you can easily debug anything in the SPA and how the data is getting crypted/uglified. I am just out of options here.

I am not interested in securing the connection, since SSL is good enough for me. The user password security is safe enough too (modern frameworks do good work here). I am just out of knowledge, how to make it harder to use the API without my SPA.
I am developing both ends, so I am able to make the API whatever I like - do you have tips, best practices, ideas?

---

Footnotes:

- SPA = Single page application (like VueJS, Angular, Ember, etc.)
- ORM = Object relational mapping (like VueX, ember-data, etc.)

Comment: since you are developing the API I assume that on authenticating, you are sending a JWT or some sort of token to the SPA.Rather than sending it as a header set it as a HTTP only cookie.The scripts running in your SPA cannot access the cookie. On subsequent requests being made to your API the browser adds this cookie to the request. In plain terms scripts(your own) cannot access your Token details, the browser sand boxes it. In case of some script injection happens in your SPA (via comments etc) they cannot hijack the session as they cannot access the JWT in the cookie.

Comment: Just a quick comment to clarify.. Vuex is by no means an ORM. It's just a global state handler with functions to mutate state.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to authenticate the call. Your application (or whatever else) connecting to the API would need to present an authentication token.

There are various ways to do that, you could for instance

- offload the authentication to someone else via [oAuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) (which is a misuse of the service, [OpenID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) should be used instead but oAuth use is common)
- have a login form in your SPA which would authenticate to your API (which in turn would provide an authentication token)

A very bad way to do that (following your comment) is to obfuscate the call, hoping that nobody will discover the secret you share between your JS code and the API.